# How to label nodes of a dendrogram with mathematical symbols?

Tags: r, latex, dendrogram, hclust

I am doing cluster analysis on some set of mathematical objects. The basic R has the functionality to plot mathematical symbols. I want to label nodes of my dendrogram with some mathematical symbols. How to incorporate this in plot function for hclust object? For instance, I want to label my nodes with letters with subscript, e.g.,

T<sub>2</sub>

How to do this in R?

Comment: Maybe latex2exp package and the `TeX()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(latex2exp)
library(dendextend)
tree <- hclust(d = dist(x = iris[1:20, 1:4])
dend <- as.dendrogram(tree)
labels(dend) <- TeX("$\\pi_2^3 (\\xi_3^4)$")
plot(dend)
```

[image]

Comment: This works well for my data. How to incorporate Greek letters in dendrogram? I am not fluent with latex2exp package.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from grayed out to filled in.

Comment: If I do not disturb you, how to incorporate parentheses an/or symbols with (simultaneously) subscripts and superscripts  in dendrograms ?

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your comment. Where would you like the parenthesis to be?